# How to remove the extra space from NSScrollView?

Tags: swift, macos, nsscrollview

**Update:**

Here is a minimal reproducible project to demonstrate the problem:
https://github.com/houmie/CocoaPlayground

**Build and start the app, then click on the menu symbol as shown below.**
[image]

---

When I add a Scrollview to my view, there is a grey space on the right-hand sight reserved for the scroller. How can I remove that and make the scroller appear when it's needed, but not reserve that grey area.

[image]

I already have it setup like this in the IB:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the size of the scroll view with Capture View Hieratchy in Xcode? What is the setting of Show scroll bars in the general system prefs?

Comment: You can't remove the space because you have the auto hide scroller switch on.  If you want to remove it, you have to turn off the switch and then manually show and hide the vertically scroller, changing the content doc width.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I can see that space is from `NSScroller` inside `NSScrollView`. The settings of `show scroll bars` is based automatically when using mouse or trackpad.

Comment: If Show Horizontal Scroller and Show Vertical Scroller are switched off then there shouldn't be any scrollers. Please post a [mre].

Comment: @Willeke Sure, I have added the project on my Github: https://github.com/houmie/CocoaPlayground. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried your project but I get "Storyboard doesn't contain a controller with identifier 'mainWindowController'". It looks like the view inside the scroll view isn't wide enough to fill the scroll view.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you for trying. You didn't read the README. ;-) I have committed a fix to make that warning to go away. Please see the edited question with instructions on how to start the app. You have to click on the symbol that appears in menu bar. Thanks

Comment: "Storyboard doesn't contain a controller with identifier 'mainWindowController'" is an exception. This means the normal flow of program execution is interrupted. Anything can go wrong after this. When I click on the star I get "[Nib Loading] Failed to connect (alwaysOnCheckBox) outlet from (CocoaPlayground.PlayController) to (NSButton): missing setter or instance variable".

Comment: @Willeke Sorry, did you pull the latest? I just cloned it into a new directory and can build and see no exception. I have fixed these two issues in this commit: https://github.com/houmie/CocoaPlayground/commit/70815a22be1f6f9666f41e5c93e9b22a1667386d

Comment: In the storyboard, the width of the scroll view is 317, the width of its document view is 287. Make the width of the document view the same as the width of its superview, the clip view.

Comment: @Willeke This is it! Thank you. I don't know how I missed that.